# Error: kilometres cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am writing a java program that converts kilometres to miles. my code is:

```
public class Ex7Program {
public void start() {
   String userKilometres;
    double kilometres = getKilometresFromUser(); 
    double miles = convertKilometresToMiles(kilometres);
    printResult(kilometres, miles);
}
private double getKilometresFromUser() { // Insert your 3 methods here.
    System.out.print("Enter kilometres: ");
    String userKilometres = Keyboard.readInput();
    double kilometres = Double.parseDouble(userKilometres);

    return kilometres;

}
private double convertKilometresToMiles(double kilometres) {
    double miles = 0.621371 * kilometres;

    return miles;
}

private void printResult(double kilometes, double miles) {
    System.out.print(kilometres + " Kilometres is " + miles + " miles ");
}
}
```

i am getting an error at the last statement that prints the results, which says:

```
Error: kilometres cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have spend long time trying fixing it, after many fail attempts i decided to come here. any suggestion where i have gone wrong? help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method parameter for printResult(double, double) is called kilometes, you need to rename it to kilometres.

Comment: thnx small mistakes like this can cost you time

Comment: Ali, I know the feeling!

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo.In arguments it is  `kilometes` and inside you wrote `kilometres`

change it to `kilometres` at both the places.

```
private void printResult(double kilometres, double miles) {
    System.out.print(kilometres+ " Kilometres is " + miles + " miles ");
    -------------------^
}
```